# Pausing a process in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I'm making a nice little Python GUI frontend for ffmpeg on Windows (one that is specifically designed to convert videos to an iPhone-friendly format and automatically import it to iTunes and tag it), and I want it to work so that you can pause the process and resume it if you want.

Since I start ffmpeg as a separate process, the obvious solution would be for the program to suspend the process (which I know is possible in Windows, Process Explorer can do it), but I can't figure out how to do it. Does anyone have any idea how to do this in Python?

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do this by using psutil ( https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil ):

```
import psutil
pid = 1034  # replace this with the pid of your process
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.suspend()
```

...to resume it:

```
p.resume()
```

Internally this is implemented in C by using SuspendThread() and ResumeThread() Windows system calls.