# Interrupt (pause) running Python program in pdb?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

In gdb, you can interrupt(pause) the program by C-c and resume.

Can you do this in pdb?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue7245) it might be fixed in Python 3.

In 2.x Ctrl-C will throw a KeyboardInterrupt, which is typically unhandled by the program, and will put the debugger into 'post-mortem' mode. You cannot continue where you left off.

I don't know if there's some other way to do what you are describing.

Answer (score 27):

No, python2's pdb doesn't support this, but you add this code to your program as a workaround:

```
def debug_signal_handler(signal, frame):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, debug_signal_handler)
```

Related questions:

- [Showing the stack trace from a running Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application)
- [enter pdb with kill signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162674/enter-pdb-with-kill-signal)

Comment: Wow, great.  Ctrl+c to stop, c to continue, exit command to exit pdb. Thank you.

Comment: It does not work for me. I get an error. ``` ValueError: I/O operation on closed file```

Comment: where would one add this code inside django project?

Answer (score 1):

This now seems to be supported, based on what was predicted in jwd's answer.

With Python 3.8, hitting Ctrl+C pauses execution, after which you can step through code & navigate up/down the execution stack using the commands listed here:

[How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues/4929267#4929267)