# how do i pass ctrl-c into subprocess popen using the stdin argument

Tags: python, subprocess

I am used to kick off command by subprocess.Popen in my python scripts. Most of them like:

```
   try:
       while True:
           line = proc.stdout.readline()
           if（proc.Poll() is not None):break;
           parse(line)
   except(KeyboardInterrupt) as E:
       kill(proc)
```

Now I have a case where a command(a simulator tool) receives "CTRL-C" into the debug mode(command line interface) to accept debug instructions, quit when exist instructions and resume to run. it seems that Popen doesn't support to pass the standard input to argument `stdin` like `stdin=input`. I know I can use os.system(cmd) which using the standard input/output as its input/output, but that is not my solution.

so someone can show me another solution? thanks in advance.

**TRY**: As Ahmed AEK said, I have a try:

```
proc = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=STDOUT)
try：
    proc.wait() #how do I get output from stdout
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    proc.wait()
```

Now, "CTRL-C"(SIGINT) can force the command into the debug mode. its function likes `os.system(cmd)`. But, how to capture the output from stdout(sys.stdout) to search some keywords that is reason why I don't use the `os.system(...)`, but `subprocess.Popen(...)`(using `proc.stdout.readline()` when `stdout=PIPE`).

Comment: updated my answer to provide direct solution for you.

Comment: thank you, Phyo Arkar Lwin
All I want is that the command will receive a 'CTRL-C' and then entry into a debug mode, continue to accept the instructions from a keyboard , finally quit from the debug mode and resume to run. as you know, the command is a kind of simualtor in my case.

Comment: I had included that part in the answer as well. .  Had you tried handling the signal handling code ?  Use the signal handler to enter into debug mode . 
If signal is send via Ctrl+C or any other singaling system it should enter to debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl+c` is a [signal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals), a signal is not passed to the standard input (by default), it's sent to all the processes connected to the terminal and each process is responsible for handling it (so both parent and child must handle the `KeyboardInterrupt` Exception or register a [signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)), forwarding stdin from parent to child is not going to change that.

if you still want to forward stdin (which only forwards text written to the console), then you could pass `stdin=sys.stdin` instead of `PIPE`.

**Edit:**
To be able to enter debug mode in child on ctrl+c, the parent must register a signal handler to skip `SIGINT` and the child must register another to [pause on ctrl+c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239760/interrupt-pause-running-python-program-in-pdb), and the child should have `stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=sys.stdout` to print and read from console.

Comment: More precisely, Control-C is intercepted by the terminal, which sends SIGINT  to each process in the current foreground process group (loosely speaking, the current foreground job and any processes spawned by that job).

Comment: thanks Ahmed AEK and chepner for your detailed explanation, now I can understand the mechanism behind this. all I want is that the command will receive a 'CTRL-C' and then entry into a debug mode, continue to accept the instructions , and finally quit from the debug mode and resume to run.

Comment: @hyperion007 the edit should answer your question

Comment: @Ahmed AEK I update my question as you said. Do you have an idea to capture output from stdout when stdout=sys.stdout. It seems that stdout can be changed dynamically. thanks again

Comment: @hyperion007, you need to make the child use a pipe instead of `sys.stdout` and have the parent read from `proc.stdout`, using `sys.stdout` makes you bypass the parent, so he won't have to read `proc.stdout` himself (which is a lot more tricky than you may think)

Answer (score 1):

You would want to send interrupt signal. Use `os.kill` or `kill -SIG $SUBPROCESS_PID` to the process id of subprocess . It is same as doing Ctrl+C but sending signal directly to the subprocess.

To do this , you need to know the PID of the Subprocess that is spawned.

```py
import signal,shlex
from subprocess import Popen
cmd = 'top'
sub_proc = Popen(shlex(cmd), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, sterr=STDOUT)
with open("./pid",'w') as f:
    f.write(sub_proc.pid)
```

Also you need to handle signal in commands you want to print debug info

```py
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('Received SIGINT  (Ctrl+C) ')

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Awaiting Signal')
signal.pause()
```

After you get the PID , you can do

`cat ./pid | kill -SIGINT`  to the process or  , from python :

```py
import os

with open("./pid",'r') as f:
   pid = int(f.read())

os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Or you can also send signal by doing `CTRL+C` its the same.

Comment: thanks , fixed. haven't got a chance to run yet.

Comment: thank for your anwser and example. No, I am not intended to kill the subprocess. Just the command submitted by subprocess will take 'CTRL-C' into a debug mode to accept debug instructions from input.

Comment: check how to handle the signal at second code block . and `os.kill` or  `kill -SIG` won't kill the process if the signal is handled  , it will send the signal in this case `SIGINT` , and whatever you have done with the signal handler will do.

Comment: @hyperion007 have you tried handling with `signal_handler`  , and do your debug mode there?

Comment: Yep, SIGINT can be transported into signal_handler and the command(simulator) was into debug mode. My script is a kind of tool which issue different commands and get their feedback to do the analysis. Now I'm in the dilemma,  I have to use the ```stdout=PIPE``` if want to get the output of command; use ```stdout=sys.stdout``` if let one command into debug mode.